# Возможно ли перенести все данные с excel в бд MySQL?

Tags: phpmyadmin, excel, mysql

Возможно ли перенести все данные с excel в бд MySQL?

Answer (score 6):

Конечно, смотрите в сторону [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php), если используете php. Если не использовать конвертацию во внутренние представления (fgetcsv), то можно кодом

```
function import_csv(
    $table,         // Имя таблицы для импорта
    $afields,       // Массив строк - имен полей таблицы
    $filename,      // Имя CSV файла, откуда берется информация 
                // (путь от корня web-сервера)
    $delim=',',         // Разделитель полей в CSV файле
    $enclosed='"',      // Кавычки для содержимого полей
    $escaped='\\',      // Ставится перед специальными символами
    $lineend='\\r\\n',      // Чем заканчивается строка в файле CSV
    $hasheader=FALSE){      // Пропускать ли заголовок CSV

if($hasheader) $ignore = "IGNORE 1 LINES ";
else $ignore = "";
$q_import = 
"LOAD DATA INFILE '".
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename."' INTO TABLE ".$table." ".
"FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$delim."' ENCLOSED BY '".$enclosed."' ".
"    ESCAPED BY '".$escaped."' ".
"LINES TERMINATED BY '".$lineend."' ".
$ignore.
"(".implode(',', $afields).")"
;
    return mysql_query($q_import);
}
```

Пример без PHP только с консолью MySQL:

```
MySQL> use %имя_бд%;
MySQL> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%путь%/%файл%.csv' INTO TABLE %имя_таблицы% FIELDS TERMINATED BY '%разделитель_значений%' enclosed by '%ковычки_содержимого%' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (%имена_столбцов%);
```

Comment: Вариант с консолью - прекрасен. Часто использую именно его для импорта из текстовых файлов.

Answer (score 4):

Через csv. Сохраните документ в Excel в формате csv, если установлен phpMyAdmin там есть возможность делать импорт, в том числе и csv файлов

Answer (score 1):

Не увероен что  dbForge  зальет инфу не убив имеющуюся, - не пробовал, но чтоб не парится этим вопросом сделал себе софтину для таких операций
Может кому пригодится. Оцените: [Перенос данных из MS Excel в базу MySQL](http://itearn.ru/goto/259)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно часто обновлять информацию лично сам пользуюсь бесплатным софтом dbForge Studio for MySQL